# Mount Windows Network Folder with Write Permissions but Without fstab Entry

Tags: windows, mount, permissions

Of course, you can mount a windows network folder quite easily in Linux/Ubuntu.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/NAME /media/USER/DIR -o username=USERNAME,password=PASWORD
```

Is there any way to grant non-root users write access to this mounted folder **without** creating an entry in `/etc/fstab`?

**Background:** I'd like to occasionally mount my folders from another computer to do some work on the files. As there are different folders all the time, it does not seem sensible to create an fstab entry every time. And as I'd like to work on the GUI, I cannot easily work with root permissions. The file permissions set for the mount folder, of course, are ignored after having the ressource mounted. Any ideas? Or is it simply not possible?

Comment: Arg! I just could have browsed the network, using the Ubuntu desktop... Well. The question remains: What is the trick to grant a common user write access to a mounted network drive without using fstab?

Answer (score 0):

So you don't mind `sudo mount` from a terminal, but you want your non-admin user(s) to have RW access?

Do once:

```
sudo mkdir /media/cifs_temp
chmod a+rwx /media/cifs_temp
```

then use a slightly modified version of your mount command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/NAME /media/cifs_temp -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD
```

and that should do it!

Comment: (currently travelling, without access to my desktop and cifs, so let me know if something doesn't work)

Comment: Except for the changed folder name, I do not see the modification?! I had already given all users full r/w-access to the mount folder - but, these permissions "change" as soon as something is mounted there. So, if I did not miss the obvious, this solution does not work :(

Comment: Btw: regarding the `sudo` and the non-admin users. I can easily have a `sudo` on the terminal, but when I'm working on the Desktop/GUI, it's not so easy becoming superuser for a while.

Comment: Yes, that was it: Changing the rights to "all" and Read+Write+Execute...